# MySQL query - to display higher 'salary'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables: *employee table* , *company table* , *works table* , *manages table* and *dependent table*.
So, what I want is to, List the employee and  his managers details, where the employees salary is greater than the managers salary

Where my tables are as follows:

```
//employee table
`Employee` (
`Ename` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL (primary key) ,
`Street` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
`City` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`joining_date` DATE NOT NULL ,
`gender` VARCHAR( 7 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `Ename` ) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;


//company table
 `Company` (
`Cname` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
`city` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `Cname` ) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;



//works table
`Works` (
`ename` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
`cname` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL (foreign key),
`salary` INT( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `ename` ) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;



//manages table
 `Manages` (
`empname` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
`manager_name` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
here ename and manager name is composite key


//dependent table
employee_dependent(
employee_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL(foreign key),
dependent_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
relation VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    gen VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(dependent_name)
);
```

Comment: Note that the '50' in 'INT(50)' is a meaningless concept

Comment: Yes sure I will change that INT(50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your query like following to get where employees salary is greater than the managers salary.

You need to join employee and works two times, one for employee and one for manager.

```
SELECT e.*,m.Ename as manager,  
FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN Manages rel on e.ename = rel.empname
    INNER JOIN Employee m on m.ename = rel.manager_name
    INNER JOIN Works we on we.ename=e.empname
    INNER JOIN  Works wm on wm.ename=m.empname
WHERE we.salary > wm.salary
```

Comment: my vote if definitely not -1 that was by mistake and i am not able to revert it

Comment: You should be able to do it now as I have edited the answer.

Comment: Its not happening i did try again. It's okay forget. Thank you for your answer though

Comment: @PSK i will upvote this answer since it is not fair to have a negative score

Comment: @Aadi you are not the one who downvoted since you don't have the needed reputation (125)

Comment: @Hadi since i don't have needed reputation that's why downvote my question?

Comment: No there are many users that downvoted your question because they didn't find it useful or unclear